# Concatenate Rows from a range and column from a

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry in advance I am a beginner in VBA maybe i am a bit confuse in my question.

Here is my function declaration :

```
Function ColorCountCustomDates(DateRaw As Range, StartDate As Integer, EndDate As Integer, LineWhereToApplyFunc As Range, CellColor As Integer)
    
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    'First step : define range between StartDate and EndDate'
    
    'Second Step : concate "LineWhereToApplyFunc" and columns from Step 1'
    
    'Call my "ColorCount" funtion with Rng = range define in step 2'
    
End Function
```

My function ask for a StartDate and a EndDate,

I search in my DateRaw all columns with StartDate <= DateRaw.Value <= EndDate (like D5:H5)
and I want that range to be reported on line "LineWhereToApplyFunc" to get my new range as (DX:HX), How can I do this last part ? Is using the Offset method a possible choice ?

Regards.

Comment: Can you clarify `" I want that range to be reported on line "LineWhereToApplyFunc" to get my new range as (DX:HX)"` please? `LineWhereToApplyFunc` is an inbound parameter (should be declared `ByVal`) our output (`ByRef`)? whats does `reported on` mean? whats `x` in `DX:HX` - it strikes me you maybe able to do this easily by using `autofilter` on `dateraw` and iterating through `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` collection of the filtered range .... would love to hear more

Comment: @JohnnieL Hello,

I'll try to clarify, I'd like my function to get 4 parameters : DateRaw (where all my dates are listed) DateStart (a cell where I enter a date) DateEnd (a cell where I enter a date) ans LineToRead (line where I want to apply another function).

Let's pretend that : DateRaw = (4:4) DateStart = 12/02/2021, DateEnd is 15/02/2021 and LineToRead = (7:7)

I want to get the Range between those two dates it might be something like (C4:F4) and transform that range in (C7:F7)

Comment: If I understand well what i'm reading for some hours now, I need something similar to the "SUM.IFS" Build in function , but I can't find a clear code that does the same in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP:

> I want to get the Range between those two dates it might be something like (C4:F4) and transform that range in (C7:F7)

Try this - A couple of observations: 1) date is too big for an `integer` so that should be a `long` 2), you *can* use the vba `find` but its quite clunky to use that: I would call the `match` worksheet function

assumes `ColorCountCustomDates` and `LineWhereToApplyFunc` are aligned so that the offset into the first range gets you to the right point of the second

not sure what happens in edge cases where dates cant be found so for illustration i assume that you want that to default to end values

Also this should probably be a sub rather than a function?

output
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub call_stacko_function()
  Dim r As Range
  
  Set r = ColorCountCustomDates(Range("4:4"), Range("a1").Value, Range("a2").Value, Range("7:7"), RGB(127, 0, 127))
  Debug.Print r.Address

End Sub


Function ColorCountCustomDates(DateRaw As Range, StartDate As Long, EndDate As Long, LineWhereToApplyFunc As Range, CellColor As Long) As Range
  
  Dim Rng As Range
    
  Dim start_col As Variant
  Dim end_col As Variant
    
    
  start_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(StartDate, DateRaw, 1)
  If IsError(start_col) Then start_col = 1
  If DateRaw.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, start_col - 1).Value < StartDate Then start_col = start_col + 1
  
  end_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(EndDate, DateRaw, 1)
  If IsError(end_col) Then end_col = DateRaw.Parent.Cells(DateRaw.Row, 1).End(xlToRight)
  
  'With LineWhereToApplyFunc.Interior
  '  .Color = xlNone
  'End With
    
  Set Rng = Range(LineWhereToApplyFunc.Cells(1, start_col), LineWhereToApplyFunc.Cells(1, end_col))

  'With Rng.Interior
  '  .Color = CellColor
  'End With

  ' Add OP function call
  ColorCount Rng  

  Set ColorCountCustomDates = Rng
End Function
```

Comment: ( I am not the one who down voted ) 

I maybe should've show you what my Colour function is about :

`Function Color(Cellule As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    If Not (Color = -4142) Then Color = CInt(Cellule.Interior.ColorIndex)
End Function

Function ColorCount(Rng As Range, CellColor As Integer)
    
    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    
    For Each cel In Rng.Cells
        If Color(cel) = CellColor Then i = i + 1

    Next cel
        ColorCount = i * 0.5
End Function`

What is the diff between sub and func ?

Comment: sub doesnt return a value, a function does. if you are not returning a value then just good practice IMHO to make it a sub. I have changed the answer to call your `ColorCount` function. Let me know if it solves your problem. Also `Color` is a keyword so may be good to change `Function Color (` in your comment, that maybe just a typo

Comment: Ok ok let me some time to understand what happens here and i'll tick your answer if it works , thanks for your time and explanations

Comment: sure - play around with match worksheet function first on the worksheet I'd suggest - that is the bit of my solution which simplifies everything the most. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match

Comment: It’s the bit I took out because you want to call your   ColourCount function - the first part clears colour of cells as the second time it’s run the range may not overlap the previous coloured cells and the second sets the new range to be coloured

Comment: I don't understand why you put "As range" when you declare the function "ColorCountCustomDates"  what does it do ?

Comment: defines the return type - functions return values https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures

Comment: Ok so I adapted a bit your code to match what I exactly want and it WORKS ! Now I have to adjust it for it to take one more column in the "end_date" because I have fused cells in my DateRaw. 

Does it works if I put a +1 somewhere in your "end_col = " line ?

Comment: great - glad it was helpful